# How can I set the value of input-group spinner to value of 1?

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Honestly thought this was an easy issue to solve, but I'm stuck trying to figure this out. I want to set my input-group spinner to show the value 1 when the user opens the application.

```
<input id="option1" type="number" min="1" value ="1"
           class="form-control"
           ng-model="targetEntity.option1">
</div>
```

I thought value="1" would solve the issue but it hasn't shown the desired result, I was wondering what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what spinner? And do you mean displaying `1` in your input field? (you can do that with `ng-init="targetEntity.option1 = 1"`)

Comment: Don't use `ng-init`, set the initial value in the controller.

Comment: `ng-init` can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of `ngInit`. You should use Components or Controllers rather than `ngInit` to initialize values on a scope. For more information, see [AngularJS ngInit Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit).

Comment: How will I go about that @Lex, I did try the ng-init but unfortunately it didn't work. Sorry, new to this.

Comment: Why don't you declare the targetEntity.option1 with a default value in your controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the value of `targetEntity.option1` in your controller:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', ($scope) => {
    $scope.targetEntity = {
      option1: 1
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input id="option1" type="number" min="1"
         class="form-control"
         ng-model="targetEntity.option1" />
</div>
```

Comment: You got it that's what i'm saying :)